# Dim the background of a progressbar

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

How do you go about Dimming the background of a progressbar? I have had a look around and saw solutions like creating a custom Dialog box?

Is this really the only way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you will have to create custom dialog box for that purpose, having set the background opacity of dialog less than 100%.

This thread contains good examples for Custom Dialog : [How to create a Custom Dialog box in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android)

Comment: Thank you, this sorted my problem out. I still find it a bit of a pain not being able to do something so simple... 

Thanks again

Comment: @x10sion There is nothing simple in the world of programming. Tackling complex situations and problems always pays off. :)